# Firebase data in combination with async promises with javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise

I have a function declared that gets Firebase data async. The function have to wait until all the data is put inside an object. For some reason the function continues without waiting until the object has been set.

```
/** Get the data content */
const getData = async (widget, userId) => {
  let promises = [];
  let mainObject = {};
  const pivotData = {};
  const pivotName =
    'user' + widget[1].type.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + widget[1].type.slice(1);

  //Object entries
  mainObject = {
    default: widget[1],
  };
  mainObject['widgetId'] = widget[0];

  //Main listner
  const mainRef = firebase
    .database()
    .ref()
    .child(widget[1].type);

  //Pivot Listner
  const pivotRef = firebase
    .database()
    .ref()
    .child(pivotName)
    .child(userId);

  //Set promise
  promises.push(
    new Promise(async resolve => {
      pivotRef
        .once('value', snapPivot => {
          snapPivot.forEach(function(result) {
            if (result.val().widgetId === widget[0]) {
              pivotData[result.key] = result.val();
              mainObject['pivot'] = pivotData;
              mainObject['typeId'] = result.key;
              mainObject['main'] = {};
              console.log('1');

              mainRef.child(result.key).once('value', snapshot => {
                console.log('2');
                mainObject['main'][result.key] = snapshot.val();
              });
            }
          });
        })
        .then(() => {
          resolve();
          console.log('3');
        });
    })
  );

  Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
    return mainObject;
  });
};
```

The expected outcome of the console.logs is 1,2,3 but it is showing 1,1,3,2

[image: Console image]

Why is the function not waiting on the `.once` function inside the loop?

Comment: You are not waiting for the promise from mainRef.child(result.key).once to resolve - that's why you are getting the logs in this order

Comment: @bastien What kind of promise do i need to put there?

Comment: Do you expect the results to be stored in the promises array and return that at the end of your function?

Comment: Yes i needs to return the mainObject that will be sent down the react application. If the mainObject needs to be stored inside an array will be not a problem.

Comment: What is your promises array used for?

Comment: It have to wait until the object (mainObject) has been set. I added the `Promise.all` in the code

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are not waiting for the promises from mainRef.child(result.key).once() to resolve.

Additionally you are only pushing one promise to your promises array you want to be pushing the promise you get when calling mainRef.child(result.key).once().

Use `await Promise.all()` [see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

```
// Reference.once returns a promise Promise<DataSnapshot>
const dataSnapshot = await pivotRef.once('value');

let promises = []; 
dataSnapshot.forEach((result) => {
  const key = result.key;
  const data = result.val();

  if (data.widgetId === widget[0]) {
    pivotData[key] = data;
    mainObject['pivot'] = pivotData;
    mainObject['typeId'] = key;
    mainObject['main'] = {};
    console.log('1');

    const promise = mainRef.child(result.key)
      .once('value', snapshot => {
        console.log('2');
        mainObject['main'][result.key] = snapshot.val();
      });        
    // add promise to our promises array
    promises.push(promise);
  }
});

// wait for all the promises to be fulfilled (i.e resolved)
await Promise.all(promises);

// assuming 3 only needs to be logged once (at the end)
console.log('3');
console.log(mainObject);
return mainObject;
```

Let me know if this works!